# What language are Enchantress and Incubus speaking?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad-2016

Enchantress and Incubus always speak some other language to each other, which is translated with subtitles for the audience. Is this a real language? A constructed language? Random gibberish with subtitles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actor who portrayed Incubus, Alain Chanoine, has said that the language ("***[moonspeak](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moonspeak)***") was invented for the film by David Ayer. It bears little relation to any *actual* language and was written down *fo-net-ick-al-ee* for them to say.

> **NR:** *What language were you speaking in the voiceovers for Incubus?*
>
> **AC:** ***Moonspeak is the language.** That’s the 4th language I speak now!*
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview with the villain of Suicide Squad](http://nerdreactor.com/2016/08/08/interview-with-the-villain-of-suicide-squad-spoilers/#PuQ7T22F4VlUPT88.99)</sup></sub>

and

> **TMN:** *How did you and Cara Delevingne master speaking in your ancient character's dialect?*
>
> **Chanoine:** *First, it was complicated because David wrote the thing down, we got to change it. I speak three different languages: Creole, French, and English. He wanted me to get more of my tone in the movie. And Cara, because she's British, she was speaking in a different way than I was, just because he wanted it to sound original to ourselves. So **I got to change a lot of the Moonspeak and he was really open. So yeah, it was fun. It was fun to make it up with him. I don't get all the vocabulary he's using, but it was fun to play with that.***
>
> <sub><sup>[‘Suicide Squad’ Actor Alain Chanoine Breaks Silence On His Top-Secret Villain](http://www.themovienetwork.com/interview/suicide-squad-actor-alain-chanoine-breaks-silence-his-top-secret-villain)</sup></sub>

Apparently it was invented by the film's sound department using a technique of [substituting nonsense words for the mouth-sounds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1w8Z0UOXVaY) made when the lines were read in English and using [ADR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubbing_(filmmaking)#ADR.2Fpost-sync) to dub them back into the film.

> *Suicide Squad presented several unique challenges, [Bach](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0045302/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr228) says, not the least of which was a late-breaking decision to have two characters speak in their own language — meaning **dialogue originally filmed in English needed to be replaced with this new language that the sound crew dubbed “moonspeak.” The solution? “Reversing and slowing the picture down, transcribing phonetically, and substituting various syllables according to their mouth shape,” Bach says, adding that Berklee helped prepare him with the problem-solving skills to tackle a challenge like that.** “I’ll never forget Dave Moulton’s first problem- solving class,” he says. “He handed us a black box with some connectors on it and asked us to draw a flow chart diagram of how it worked…I use that kind of logic—or try to—daily.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Summer’s Top Films Fueled by Music and Sound from Berklee Alumni](https://www.berklee.edu/news/summer-films-fueled-berklee-alumni)</sup></sub>

Answer (score -2):

It could possibly be Hebrew (maybe the old Hebrew) since they are supposedly natives of the ancient Egyptian realm however it could be a mixture of Hebrew and Arabic as well...the audio clip is sketchy and there isn't a good copy of the film online to revisit the scene...

Comment: I thought they uncovered the doll in South America?

Comment: Ancient Egyptians were speaking the Ancient Egyptian language. They had a writing system called Hieroglyphs. It has nothing to do with Hebrew.